# How do I authorize a service to call an API using Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have a service that gets an access token from Azure AD.  I have an API that I would like to accept that token as authorization.

My service code to call the API is

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient()
{
  BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44372/")
};

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, client.BaseAddress + "api/todolist");
request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

The response I get back is a `401 - Unauthorized`.

I have a feeling that the issue is in the API `ConfigureServices` function; specifically (this was taken from an example, so I don't really know what it means yet):

```
services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
});
```

I'm new to Azure and authentication in general so I don't know what options are available or appropriate. I also am not sure how to set up the applications in Azure to allow this. I have the application id of the service set up as an Authorized client application of the API; it is also listed int the knownClientApplications in the API manifest.

There are just so many knobs to turn, I have no idea where to go from here. If anyone can let me know some things to try, that would be outstanding.

Thanks

Comment: My article might help: https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-authentication-aspnet-core-api-part-1.

Comment: The article above should be helpful, if you solve your issue, you could post the answer here to help others.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code sample on how to call a web API in an ASP.NET Core web app using Azure AD:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore/calling-a-web-api-in-an-aspnet-core-web-application-using-azure-ad/

> This sample contains a web API running on ASP.NET Core 2.0 protected by Azure AD. The web API is accessed by an ASP.NET Core 2.0 web application on behalf of the signed-in user. The ASP.NET Web application uses the OpenID Connect middleware and the Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL.NET) to obtain a JWT bearer token for the signed-in user using the OAuth 2.0 protocol. The bearer token is passed to the web API, which validates the token and authorizes the user using the JWT bearer authentication middleware.